# unit test convert to dto extension method with fluentconversion

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-assertions

if i have a extension method that converts an `Person` object  to a `PersonDTO` then

1. should i unit test that the conversion occurs correctly
2. if so and i use `fluentassertions` how do i assert that the conversion is correct

my extension method is:

```
public static PersonDTO ToDto (this Person person)
    {
        if (person == null) return null;
        return new PersonDTO
        {
            FirstName = person.FirstName,
            LastName = person.LastName,
            Dob = person.Dob,
            Identifier= person.Id
        };            
    }
```

my person object has other properties that are not being mapped.

to get the personDTO object i would therefore do something similar to below:

```
var newPerson = new Person{ //set properties here };
var personDto = newPerson.ToDto();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, this code should be tested.

In order to check that the conversion is correct, you have to build the expected result manually, and then assert that the result of the function is the same:

```
var person = new Person{ ... };
var expectedPersonDto = new PersonDto{ ... };
person.ToDto().Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedPersonDto);
```

See [this](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/) for more information on comparing object graphs.

Comment: ok thanks - i thought that might be the case - creating the expected result could be quite tedius if objects has lot of properties.

Comment: Indeed, which is why you might want to create builders that create those objects. See [here](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html).

Comment: Or compare it an anonymous type that has the properties that you care about. FA will ignore the rest.

However, I would not test those individual methods, but test it as part of the API that exposes it.